# Fast CSV reading from network drive

Tags: c#

I have a csv flat file system on a network drive from which at any point of time I read about 500-600 csv files each with several thousand lines. I'm currently using the following piece of code to do the reading,

```
var parser = new TextFieldParser(fileName) {TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited};
parser.SetDelimiters(",");
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    var fields = parser.ReadFields();
}
```

But even this takes pretty long. I'm looking to speed things up significantly. Can anyone suggest something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had good results with this [CSV parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) at Codeplex.

But I strongly recommend to analyze your code to find out where the real bottleneck is, the network drive, the CSV parser or the data processing after it's parsed.

**Update:**

A very pragmatic approach for identifying the bottleneck could be to measure the total execution time for the following tasks:

1. Copying the files from the network drive to your local drive using the Windows file explorer (time for data transfer).
2. Reading the files from the network drive with a simple .NET program, e.g. using the *StreamReader* class (time for data transfer from a .NET program).
3. Reading and parsing the files from the network drive with a CSV parser (time for data transfer plus time for parsing).
4. Reading, parsing and processing the files with a CSV parser and whatever is required for the data processing (time for data transfer plus time for parsing plus time for processing).

With these numbers, it should be rather easy to identify where the biggest potential for improvement is. Depending on which step takes the most time, you can then look into your network infrastructure, experiment with different CSV parser or further analyze where the data processing spends most time.

Comment: how would I actually go about doing that? Can I profile my applications somehow?

Comment: I've added a possible approach in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure how to compare against "pretty long", but I have had good experiences using [Lumen CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx), which is a stream based, forward-only csv parser.